# Selenium Ide - How to check specific css properties

Tags: selenium, ide

How can I add assertions to check specific css properties of an element, for example height or padding-left?
In Java with webdriver it is possible. But how can I do that with Selenium IDE?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide a detailed explanation of the problem, along with the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem and your expected output and any error messages.

Comment: be specific please

Answer (score 1):

You can try execute script function. See my example below:

[image]

Here is test output:

[image]

Inside `getComputedStype` you need to use JS way to look up the element you need and then invoke `getPropertyValue` with the value you would like to assert. Being saved to a variable (in my case it is `${WDTH}`) you will be able to test your property for a specific value.